# How can I strip whitespace from within a python regex group

Tags: python, regex, string

Is it possible to perform a regex sub on a group from within another regex sub in python?  I'd like to remove all square brackets and replace all spaces within square brackets with underscores.  I'm able to remove the square brackets without issue, but I can't figure out how to remove the spaces from those chunks of text within the brackets (without removing spaces outside of the square brackets).

```
foo = 'select [table name].[column name] from [table name]'

re.sub('\[(.*?)\]', re.sub('\s', '_',r'\1'), foo)
```

results in:
'select table name.column name from table name'

The output I'm trying to achieve is:
'select table_name.column_name from table_name'

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: @wp78de that doesn't work for the whole string. More logic is still required to get correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lambda` and `replace()` in `re.sub()`.

```
re.sub(r'\[(.*?)\]', lambda m: m.group(1).replace(" ", "_"), text)
```

Output:

```
select table_name.column_name from table_name
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/tlhwrl)

Comment: @S.Jovan My bad, I thought it could be done with a regex (my attempt: https://regex101.com/r/lehhgv/1/) but using `re.sub` with that does not work as expected, so your sol is definitely the best!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function .replace(what you want to replace , to what you want to replace).

Comment: This doesn't work as the OP wants to only replace the spaces *inside* brackets with underscores... `replace` does everything

Comment: the question asks explicitly for a regex solution